# Can a docstring consist of multiple string literals?

Tags: python, syntax, multiline, string-literals, docstring

Can a Python docstring be written as a series of one-line string literals? For example, instead of

```
def bar():
  """My function.

  That does foo.
  """
  ...
```

to write

```
def bar():
  "My function.\n"
  "\n"
  "That does foo.\n"
  ...
```

I understand this might seem a little bit odd and much less readable. The reason why I want to do this is that I'm implementing a Python code generator/pretty printer. The problem with docstrings is that they aren't a syntactic feature, they are strings with special meaning. And my representation of Python code is purely syntactic, therefore I can't distinguish if a string is a docstring or not. Therefore I need a way how to pretty print all strings uniformly in a way that doesn't change their content (for example the exact value of a multi-line docstring depends on indentation).

Comment: You can test this for yourself by getting the `__doc__` of the documented function/etc. afterwards.

Comment: What you have written is not a docstring. Docstrings are the first element inside the method body, not before it as you have shown.

Comment: I didn't think it would be good to include it in my answer, but I've written a Python formatter which handles a good portion of the tokenizing already for you, might help: https://github.com/WoLpH/python-formatter

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Thanks for reminding me, of course, I'll fix the question (I'm more used to languages that put docs before a statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the first string would be considered the docstring of the function. Also, it has to come **after** the def, not before.

```
>>> def bar():
...   """My function.
...   
...   That does foo.
...   """
...   pass
... 
>>> bar.__doc__
'My function.\n  \n  That does foo.\n  '
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def bar():
...   "My function.\n"
...   "\n"
...   "That does foo.\n"
...   pass
... 
>>> bar.__doc__
'My function.\n'
```

Based on the example in your question, you're probably looking for "**additional docstrings**". From [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/):

> String literals occurring elsewhere in Python code may also act as documentation. They are **not recognized by the Python bytecode compiler and are not accessible as runtime object attributes (i.e. not assigned to `__doc__`)**, but two types of extra docstrings may be extracted by software tools:
>
> 1. String literals occurring immediately after a simple assignment at the top level of a module, class, or `__init__` method are called "attribute docstrings".
> 2. String literals **occurring immediately after another docstring** are called "additional docstrings".

[PEP 258](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) -- Docutils Design Specification gives more information on attribute and [additional docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0258/#additional-docstrings).

Answer (score 2):

No, they won't get concatenated in the case of docstrings at least

```
In [1]: def a():
   ...:     'some '
   ...:     'text '
   ...:     'here '
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [2]: def b():
   ...:     '''some
   ...:     text
   ...:     here
   ...:     '''
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [3]: a.__doc__
Out[3]: 'some '

In [4]: b.__doc__
Out[4]: 'some\n    text\n    here\n    '
```

This is understandable since these 2 are also completely different statements:

```
a = '''
some
text
'''

b = 'some'
'text'
```